# Gaussian Elimination Inverse Matrix

Tags: c++, math, matrix-inverse

What does you block of code shown below do? I'm confused

```
  if (temp != j)
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * dimension; k++) {
            temporary = augmentedmatrix[j][k];
            augmentedmatrix[j][k] = augmentedmatrix[temp][k];
            augmentedmatrix[temp][k] = temporary;
        }
```

Comment: You assume your read from the file is successful.

Comment: Warning! The determinant of your example matrix is zero, thus it hasn't an inverse! :-) You will get division by zero even with a perfect code :-)

Comment: at the moment this doesn't matter, but yes, change any of the numbers to make det not zero

Comment: Done this now, didn't notice that *embarrased face*

Comment: This is not an error, if matrix is degenerate then the process of gauss-jordan elimination will end and you will find the actual rank of the matrix.Yuo won't get division by zero because you don't use division by det in GJ procedure

Comment: @user3000403 please put it into another question and restore the previous content of this one to make things in right order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
the original question was how to compute inverse matrix with Gaussian Elimination. OP has stucked on the actual elimination part of the algorithm.

---

now if element 1,1 is not zero then you are going to zero element 2,1 using matrix elementary operations:

> - F_s,t  - interchange rows s and t
> - F_s,t_(a)  - add row t*a to s
> - F_s_(a) - multiply row s by a

You can also start by zeroing 1,2 element.

These operations correspond to elementary matrices ( and to linear transformation matrices). Because each invertible matrix can be expressed as product of some elementary matrices

```
A = P1,...,Pk,Ql,...,Q1
```

which are invertible, we can retrieve inverse of `A, A_inverse` by applying corresponding operations to original matrix `A`, and this is the same as multiplication `A` by `P,Q`:

```
A_inverse = Q1_inv,...,Ql_inv,Pk_inv,...,P1_inv
```

> For each row in a matrix, if the row does not consist of only zeros,
>   then the left-most non-zero entry is called the leading coefficient
>   (or pivot) of that row. So if two leading coefficients are in the same
>   column, then a row operation of type 3 (see above) could be used to
>   make one of those coefficients zero. Then by using the row swapping
>   operation, one can always order the rows so that for every non-zero
>   row, the leading coefficient is to the right of the leading
>   coefficient of the row above. If this is the case, then matrix is said
>   to be in row echelon form. So the lower left part of the matrix
>   contains only zeros, and all of the zero rows are below the non-zero
>   rows. The word "echelon" is used here because one can roughly think of
>   the rows being ranked by their size, with the largest being at the top
>   and the smallest being at the bottom.

now basically you should store augmented matrix

```
float augmentedmatrix[maximum][2*maximum] ;
```

so you can perform operations on matrix `A` and on identity matrix simultaneously.

Fill identity matrix:

```
/* augmenting with identity matrix of similar dimensions */

     for(i=0;i<dimension; i++)
      for(j=dimension; j<2*dimension; j++)
          if(i==j%dimension)
             augmentedmatrix[i][j]=1;
          else
             augmentedmatrix[i][j]=0;
```

and perform Gauss-Jordan elimination on the extended matrix by:

```
/* finding maximum jth column element in last (dimension-j) rows */
/* swapping row which has maximum jth column element */
/* performing row operations to form required identity matrix 
   out of the input matrix */
```

What you are missing is:

```
/* using gauss-jordan elimination */
for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
    temp = j;
    /* finding maximum jth column element in last (dimension-j) rows */
    for (i = j + 1; i < dimension; i++)
        if (augmentedmatrix[i][j] > augmentedmatrix[temp][j])
            temp = i;

    if (fabs(augmentedmatrix[temp][j]) < minvalue) {
        printf("\n Elements are too small to deal with !!!");
        return -1;
    }
    /* swapping row which has maximum jth column element */
    if (temp != j)
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * dimension; k++) {
            temporary = augmentedmatrix[j][k];
            augmentedmatrix[j][k] = augmentedmatrix[temp][k];
            augmentedmatrix[temp][k] = temporary;
        }
    /* performing row operations to form required identity matrix out 
       of the input matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        if (i != j) {
            r = augmentedmatrix[i][j];
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * dimension; k++)
                 augmentedmatrix[i][k] -= augmentedmatrix[j][k] *
                                                   r / augmentedmatrix[j][j];
        } else {
            r = augmentedmatrix[i][j];
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * dimension; k++)
                augmentedmatrix[i][k] /= r;
        }
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but I don't get how to start programming it

Comment: OK, I think I understand the algorithm enough to write finish my program. Thanks

Comment: @user3000403 please put it into another question and restore the previous content of this one to make things in right order